# Postgres - how to manage losing a tablespace

Tags: disaster-recovery, postgresql-13

I have a postgres 13 database installed on an SSD drive. 90% of the tables and indexes are in a tablespace on the SSD drive.

I also have a 2nd hard disk (magnetic HDD) which contains a 2nd tablespace, and two extremely large (partitioned) tables which contain old, archived data.

The HDD has failed, the postgres tablespace is no long available, any attempt to SELECT from either table on the lost tablespace results in an error.

Other than that, the database seems fine. I can connect normally, select from all the other tables and run all my normal applications.

If I can accept the loss of the tablespace and it's two tables, is there anyway to tidy-up the remaining database and restore integrity? Please note - I'm *not* asking how to restore my lost tablespace, just how to manage the loss cleanly.

There are some old (5 years plus) threads along similar lines, but they mostly seem to suggest that the loss of a tablespace leads to the loss of the database - which doesn't seem to be the case with this one.